# PHP numfmt_create call to undefined function

Tags: php

Hiii,
While working with numfmt_create function, I'm having problem with access it..
I had enabled php_intl.dll in my php.ini(php -v = 5.5.12).
But i had called the same numfmt_create from the cmd it works fine.
In browser shows me call to undefined function.

Any help will be apprecitated,

Thank you.

I had used the following code

```
<?php numfmt_create(); ?>
```

When i called from browser
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function numfmt_create() in C:\wamp\www\num.php on line 1

when i called from cmd

warning: numfmt_create() expects 2 parameters...

Comment: Please show us your code and the exact error message you get

Comment: and your extension is loaded? you restart the server? make a file.php with phpinfo() inside and see your extension

Comment: Yeah i had restarted and it works fine in cmd.. but when i called in browser it doesn't shoot up!!

Comment: @varathanyajiv This function needs arguments! See the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.create.php

Comment: Yes... I understand it... im having a bigger functionality it will make time to make it all posted here... so i just posted a single function to make it understand easier...

Answer (score 9):

Turn on "intl" function from your PHP version(php.ini).

Comment: You also have to make sure that php-intl is installed, otherwise (e.g.) apt-get install php7.4-intl

Comment: And restart your webserver after installation. If running Apache, a graceful restart is sufficient: `apacectl -k graceful`

Answer (score -1):

You not installed intl. Uncomment extension intl in php.ini.

Intl on gitHub
https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers

Comment: No, problem. I wanted to help, but did not see that they had already given an answer. Sorry

Answer (score -2):

Read the doc:

> http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.create.php

You must pass at least two params:

```
<?php
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'de_DE', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL );
echo numfmt_format($fmt, 1234567.891234567890000)."\n";
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'it', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT );
echo numfmt_format($fmt, 1142)."\n";
?>
```

Comment: @varathanyajiv you got some advance?